# How Can I Set Four Different Background images using CSS?

Tags: html, flexbox, background, grid

```css
.education {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.8), rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.5)),
    url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random1), no-repeat fixed, url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random2), no-repeat fixed, url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random3), no-repeat fixed, url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random4), no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    
}
```

```html
 <section id="education" class="education">
            <div class="content-wrap">
            <h2>Education</h2>

            <!-- School details: copy this whole block to add more schools. -->
            <h3>Andela - Lagos, Nigeria</h3>
            <p>Mobile Web Specialist Certificate, 2019</p>
            <p>Five Months Learning Program. </p>

            <h3>University Of  Lagos - Akoka, Lagos</h3>
            <p>Bachelor of Science, 2013-2017</p>
            <p>Major in Economics and International Trade.</p>

            <h3>Kith and Kin International College - Ikorodu, Lagos</h3>
            <p>West African Exam Council Certificate, 2009-2013</p>
            <p> Major in Commerce.</p>
          </div>
        </section>
```

I want to add four different background images behind my education section, but my code only adds one image four times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert commas after the end of each comma declaration which when being rendered breaks the order since a declaration after the first comma it reads a value of just `,no-repeat fixed,` by itself instead of having those attributes attached to the parameter that expects them and it gracefully errors and stops on the first image.

Next issue is that if you genuinely want them to appear connected as I think you want, you'll need to specify the X `background-position` argument in the image declarations as well to step through the added image sizes which in your example are a nice consistent 200px each to provide the margin from the left side of the container. See example for more detail and hope this helps, cheers!

```css
.education {
    background:
      linear-gradient(rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.8), 
                      rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.5)),
      url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random1) no-repeat left, 
      url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random2) no-repeat 200px, 
      url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random3) no-repeat 400px, 
      url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random4) no-repeat 600px;
    background-size: contain;
    
}
```

```html
<section id="education" class="education">
    <div class="content-wrap">
    <h2>Education</h2>

    <!-- School details: copy this whole block to add more schools. -->
    <h3>Andela - Lagos, Nigeria</h3>
    <p>Mobile Web Specialist Certificate, 2019</p>
    <p>Five Months Learning Program. </p>

    <h3>University Of  Lagos - Akoka, Lagos</h3>
    <p>Bachelor of Science, 2013-2017</p>
    <p>Major in Economics and International Trade.</p>

    <h3>Kith and Kin International College - Ikorodu, Lagos</h3>
    <p>West African Exam Council Certificate, 2009-2013</p>
    <p> Major in Commerce.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please, my images are overlapping on top of each other, and it's making it not span 100% of my browser window.  This is my updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/Temitope/61pz03hy/11/